# Why bash expansion get different result with zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have the following directory structure:

[demo.zip]:

- _rels

  - .rels
- docProps

  - app.xml
  - core.xml
- xl

  - _rels

    - workbook.xml.rels
  - theme

    - theme1.xml
  - worksheets

    - sheet1.xml
  - sharedStrings.xml
  - styles.xml
  - workbook.xml
- [Content_Types].xml

When I invoke the following command(with bash):

```
echo ./**/*.xml
```

It outputs the folloing, with some result missing:

```
docProps/app.xml
docProps/core.xml
xl/sharedStrings.xml
xl/styles.xml
xl/workbook.xml
```

However, if I use zsh, it outputs all the xml files, like below:

```
[Content_Types].xml
docProps/app.xml
docProps/core.xml
xl/sharedStrings.xml
xl/styles.xml
xl/theme/theme1.xml
xl/workbook.xml
xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
```

Why do I get the different result with bash and zsh?

Comment: Aside from the correct answer you already got to this question: Why, in general, would you expect Zsh identical to bash? There are different languages. They share a common subset, and if you are very careful, you can write programs which operate the same under both (though, what's the point in doing so?).

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not recognize `**` as recursive search by default.

You can enable this in Bash 4+ with

```
shopt -s globstar
```